# Counting the number of each unique value in regards to another column (oracle g11)

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I'm trying to do the following with a dataset I have that looks like this:

```
letter  number
a   1
a   2
a   1
a   1
a   3
a   4
a   2
a   4
b   1
b   3
b   4
b   3
b   2
b   5
b   1
b   1
```

the dataset is the result of a sub query I have run. I want to format the data to look like this, so I can flag the ones that have a count higher than 3

```
letter number number_count
    a   1   3
    a   2   2
    a   3   1
    a   4   2
    b   1   3
    b   2   1
    b   3   2
    b   4   1
    b   5   1
```

So for each value in the letter column, I need each unique number in col 2 counted up and displayed next to the value itself.
I've done a lot of searching to try and solve this and can't get any variation of count, count distinct, over or other code to work so I'm either underestimating the problem or more likely, I'm not sure how to phrase my search so I find the answer I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm using sql developer to access an oracle 11g database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i think the following is what you are looking for:

```
select letter, number, count(letter) as number_count from table group by letter, number;
```

Comment: This seems to have done exactly as I needed, thank you very much for your help. It seems I was having trouble by not understanding "group by" properly.

Answer (score 0):

I added two more data lines to show an example where you'll have one result that's flagged.

```
 WITH
      sub_q AS (
           SELECT 'a' AS letter_column, 1 AS value_column FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'a', 2 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'a', 1 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'a', 1 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'a', 3 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'a', 4 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'a', 2 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'a', 4 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'b', 1 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'b', 3 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'b', 4 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'b', 3 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'b', 2 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'b', 5 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'b', 1 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'b', 1 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'b', 1 FROM Dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'b', 1 FROM DUal
      )

 SELECT
      letter_column,
      value_column,
      COUNT(value_column) AS value_count,
      CASE 
           WHEN COUNT(value_column) > 3 THEN 1
           ELSE NULL
      END AS flag_gt_3
 FROM sub_q
 GROUP BY
      letter_column,
      value_column
 ORDER BY
      letter_column,
      value_column
 ;
```

Comment: To be clear -- using COUNT(value_column) assumes every row has a value in your value column.If you have rows with NULLs in the value column and you DO want to also flag results where a particular letter has more than 3 NULLs, you should use COUNT(*) rather than COUNT(value_column). A NULL cannot be evaluated, which is why COUNT(value_column) provides a different result